# Wrong Number of Characters returned by Len

Tags: vb.net

I am new to VB and have a simple program. I just want the program to display in a message box the number of characters in a long variable. I am using the Len() function. The code is as follows.

```
        Try

        Dim num As Long = 1230456985623145
        Dim numLength As Long

        numLength = Len(num)
        MessageBox.Show(numLength.ToString())

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

Simple. However when i run the function, it returns a value of 8 instead of the actual value. Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong. Do i need to add anything else to obtain the right value

Comment: You're describing a problem using `num` in your code, however the variable you're measuring is `name`.

Comment: What's the value of `name`? Do you want `Len(name)` or `Len(num.ToString)`?

Comment: I'd also suggest, considering that you mention being new to VB, you avoid using functions like "Len" from the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace; it'll make any future transition to languages such as C# much easier.

Answer (score 4):

It should be like this:

```
Dim num As Long = 1230456985623145
Dim numLength As Long

numLength = Len(num.ToString())
MessageBox.Show(numLength.ToString())
```

If you forgot to use ToString(), Len function returns the number of bytes required to store the variable, which is 8 because a Long variable requires 8 byte to store.

**Definition of [Len function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxsw58z6(v=vs.90).aspx) in MSDN:**

> Returns an integer containing either the number of characters in a
>   string or the nominal number of bytes required to store a variable.

**In your original code (before your edit):**

You use Name as a parameter in your Len function. Since your code is a WinForm, the Name is a property of the Form. Check the value of the Name using:

```
MessageBox.Show(Name)
```

**String.Length**

Using the Length property of a string is more preferable. Like Adrian Wragg said, it's easier to convert your codes between the languages which are supported by .Net (C#, VB and F#).